# Angular 2 doesn't save my Authentication Cookie with CORS

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, cross-domain

I have an angular 2 app which should authenticate to a Node Express backend where it sends an login request to the backend and receives a cookie. It should send this cookie with every consecutive request (which it does not).

I have in my angular app:

class **LoginService**

```
private requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true});`


    login(username: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
     return this.http.post(this.myUrl + "login",
     JSON.stringify({username:username, password: password}), this.requestOptions)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => true)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

some **DataService**

```
private requestOptions =  new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true})

getData(): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.myUrl, this.requestOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then (res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
    }
```

On my node backend, I have:

```
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", http://localhost:4200);
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept');
```

When I send the login request in angular, I can see that it got accepted on the server side, but when i send a consecutive request, it gives me 401 Not authorized, which is the error I send if your not authenticated.

However, when i send the login request via HttpRequester (Firefox Plugin for HTTP Requests), i can access all the data in my angular app.

My angular version is 2.4.10

+++ UPDATE +++

So, i made some tests and I found out, that my authentication works fine, as long as I use the same service.

I have a service called **login.service.ts** and a service called **data.service.ts**.

**What I can do:**
Login via **login.service.ts** and fetch the data via **login.service.ts**.

**What I can't do:**
Login via **login.service.ts** and continue to use **data.service.ts**.

This is not very practical for my use case.
Does someone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3):

By default angular is not sending cookies. Try pass `{ withCredentials: true }` to your RequestOptions:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
this.http.post(this.connectUrl, <stringified_data> , options);
```

Comment: I did define request options in both requests, the login and the other one. Did i Do it the wrong way?

Comment: Did you provide `withCredentials: true` ?

Comment: It says new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true}). Is this correct?

Comment: If you have any headers, then yes. If not you can simply provide `{withCredentials: true}`

Comment: Well, for the GET Request, I actually don't need any headers. But the behaviour doesn't change, if i leave them out.

However, if I don't use the login request in my angular app, but execute the request with an HTTP Request plugin for my browser, I can continue in my angular app with all the other requests

Comment: i have updated my question. Can you provide some more help? :)

Answer (score 2):

I had your situation. With Maciej answer I solved my problem. 
I added the `{ withCredentials: true }` to my request options that already had the headers.

Then server-side, on my express base file `server.js`, i added

```
var cors = require("cors");
var corsSettings = {
  origin: true,
  methods: ['POST'],
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsSettings));
```

I actually excluded the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, so my only header (server-side) is

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers");
    next();
});
```

Just wanna point out that as Maciej mentioned, you need some body in your request. So even if your query doesn't need it you need to call it with an empty body string.

```
const jsonHeads = new Headers();
jsonHeads.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
jsonHeads.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
jsonHeads.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, access-control-allow-origin');
options = { headers : myHeaders, withCredentials: true }
this.http.post('http://myApi:8080/list', '', options);
```

This way, angular started sending cookies and authenticating properly. I hope this helps. I needed this myself a couple of hours ago.